# Python Shelve PyQt4 objects TypeError: the sip.wrapper type cannot be instantiated or sub-classed

Tags: python, c++, save, pyqt4, shelve

I am having trouble pickling PyQt4 objects. I can pickle normal objects but my class that one of the attributes is a `PyQt4` object it gives me this error:

> TypeError: the sip.wrapper type cannot be instantiated or sub-classed

I have done a lot of reading, and learned from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22889876/python-pickle-and-qt-pyqt) that only few pyqt4 objects can be pickled but my objects are beyond the scope of those objects. I understood that this happens because pyqt4 objects are `c++` extensions objects. A lot of answers explained *why* this happens, but none offered a good working *solution*. I am using the `shelve` module.

The PyQt4 objects that I am using are `QLayout`, `QLabel`, `QStackedWidget`, and `QWidget`. They each have their own properties that contain **more** PyQt4 items(i.e. `QFont` for the `Qlabel`s), but I don't think that matters.

Could anyone please offer a good solution to store these objects to a shelve in python saving all their properties?

Comment: A solution to what? You haven't described what these objects are, or what properties of them you need to save.

Comment: @ekhumoro, I have edited the question

Comment: There is no way to do what you are asking, for the reasons already stated in the accepted answer for the question you linked to. And just like that question, I strongly suspect that this is just another [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: @ekhumoro, is there **absolutely no way** to achieve this? I'm sure there **must** be some solution.

Comment: @ekhumoro, so is there any other way to save pyqt4 objects? other than `shelve` and `pickle` that don't work?

Comment: You need to be very specific about what you mean by "save". This implies that that you also need to explain your use-case much more clearly.

Comment: @ekhumoro, by 'save' I mean to store them. I have a lot layouts with a lot of widgets and it takes a lot of time to create the qlayout and add all the widgets to the layouts and process them, etc. I realized instead of doing it every time I could just save them in a file or shelve and then get it from the shelve instead of waiting for everything to start up.

Comment: If the application start-up is slow, that is entirely due to inefficiencies in your own code. It has got nothing to do with creating the layouts/widgets, which mostly happens in C++, not Python. If you need help to improve your code so that start-up time is faster, you will need to provide a [mcve].

Comment: @ekhumoro, I don't think for this you need an example. if a simple explanation isn't enough. let me know and I will post my code. I did a little debugging and I found out that what takes all the time is when I call `MainWindow.show()` and I don't why that takes so much time. Because, I have a lot of layouts to process big files and I use a `QStackedWidget` to get them together and let the user switch between them. I start with the first page, and just a simple layout with under 50 widgets is what takes so long. do you know why?