# How to pickle a dictionary with classes in the hash?

Tags: python, serialization, pyqt, pyqt4, pickle

So I have an program with the list of Class's (TestEVAL) and a I use a QMdiArea to present the multiple Class data in a subwindow.  I am trying to enhance my pickle to include the QSubwindow data which is stored in it's subwindow widget with the following code:

```
    with open(fname, 'wb') as fout:
        for dataset in self.datasets:
            # Temp save chdlg - do not want saved
            ochdlg = dataset.chdlg
            dataset.chdlg = None
            pickle.dump(dataset, fout)
            # Restore chdlg
            dataset.chdlg = ochdlg
        pickle.dump('plots', fout)
        for sub in self.mdi.subWindowList():
            mw = sub.widget()
            old_plot = dict()
            old_plot['title'] = sub.windowTitle()
            old_plot['setup'] = mw.setup
            pickle.dump(old_plot, fout)
            pickle.dump(mw.channels, fout)
    fout.close()
```

At which point I get a:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "TestEVAL.pyw", >line 1448, in saveas_session
>      pickle.dump(mw.channels, fout)
>    File "AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\copy_reg.py", >line 71, in _reduce_ex
>      state = base(self)
>   TypeError: the sip.wrapper type cannot be instantiated or sub-classed

Since mw.channels is a dict with hash values from self.datasets (not a simple object) I think I need to do something more?  Maybe I need to implement a .**setstate**() and .**getstate**() (with __ before and after!)  But I do not understand what it returns in getstate.  The dataset class is large so I do not want to duplicate it's pickle information.  I could add a dataset.id and hash the mw.channels[dataset.id] but this is not clear to me.  furthermore, mw.channels[dataset] = values and values is a list of another Class (headers) with Meta states associated (not too big data wise).  What do I do?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/22889876/984421 (including all the comments).

Comment: Yes - I looked at that - the Class I have (TestEVAL) does not have a PyQt class within - I am not trying to pickle a Qthing that is not picklable (I think?)  Many of the stackoverflow questions on pickle seem to be of a dict that whose hash key is simple data type - I think it does not work when the has key is complex, so how to fix it?

Comment: The `TypeError` in your question relates to the `sip.wrapper` type, which is the one of the base-classes of PyQt classes such as `QWidget` and `QObject`.

Comment: Ah - I see - need to post a new version of the fixed routine... But now that I remove the QThing causing problem - all is well.